# Boost variate_generator - writing and restoring its state

Tags: boost, random, state

I have encountered a problem with concerning the state of a random number generator. Specifically, a saved engine state once restored, generates a sequence of random numbers that is slightly off. In all cases, the restored sequence appears to have been shifted one up or down. For example:

```
1. Create bivariate generator with an MT19937 engine and a standard uniform distribution.
2. Generate some random normal variables.
3. Save the state of the engine. I'll call it state 1.
4. Generate and keep track of the next 5 random normal variables.
5. Repeat steps 2 to 4 to obtain a state 2 and then a state 3.
```

Observed results (for illustration only):

```
State 1
Actual  Restored state (appears to have shifted up)
a       b
b       c
c       d
d       e
e       f

State 2
Actual  Restored state (appears to have shifted down)
j       i
k       j
l       k
m       l
n       m

State 3
Actual  Restored state (appears to have shifted up again)
r       s
s       t
t       u
u       v
v       w
```

Code:

```
boost::mt19937 engine(seed);
boost::normal_distribution<double> dd(0, 1);
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::normal_distribution<double>> rr(engine, dd);
std::stringstream ss1; std::stringstream ss2; std::stringstream ss3;

for (long p=0; p<20; p++) {rr();} 
ss1 << engine;
for (long p=0; p<5; p++) {
  std::cout << rr() << "\n"; // keep track of these
}

// repeat for states 2 and 3, i.e., ss2 and ss3

ss1 >> engine; 
for (long p=0; p<5; p++) {
  std::cout << rr() << "\n"; // compare with the above numbers
} 

// repeat for states 2 and 3
```

My Boost version is 1.47.0 and I'm compiling the code in VS2010 for 64-bit Windows. Would be very grateful for any advice to try to "re-align" these saved states. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the `normal_distribution` instance is maintaining some of its own state across calls to the generator, in addition that held by the engine itself. The distribution has a `reset` method specifically for clearing it out. From the [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/random/normal_distribution.html#id1252338-bb):

> Effects: Subsequent uses of the distribution do not depend on values
>   produced by any engine prior to invoking reset.

Calling `rr.distribution().reset()` immediately prior to saving or loading engine state will ensure identical results across reloads.